# Chat en vivo con Node.js

Tags: nodejs, socket.io, nosql

he seguido un tutorial para hacer un chat en linea pero a la hora de usar socket.io no lo encuentra.
Este es el tutorial que utilicé
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/simple-chat-application-in-node-js-using-express-mongoose-and-socket-io-ee62d94f5804/

Este es mi server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');





app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
var Message = mongoose.model('Message',{name:'String',message:'String'});
var dbUrl = 'mongodb+srv://dayton:Siegfried62@mymongodb-ijvjf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true';

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
  Message.find({},(err, messages)=> {
    res.send(messages);
  })
})


app.get('/messages/:user', (req, res) => {
  var user = req.params.user
  Message.find({name: user},(err, messages)=> {
    res.send(messages);
  })
})

app.post('/messages', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    var message = new Message(req.body);

    var savedMessage = await message.save()
      console.log('saved');

    var censored = await Message.findOne({message:'badword'});
      if(censored)
        await Message.remove({_id: censored.id})
      else
        io.emit('message', req.body);
      res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch (error){
    res.sendStatus(500);
    return console.log('error',error);
  }
  finally{
    console.log('Message Posted')
  }

});

io.on('connection', () =>{ console.log('a user is connected')});
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, (err) =>{ console.log("Conexion establecida",err);});

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server is running on port', server.address().port);
});
```

este es mi index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <br>
            <div class=''>
                <h1 class='display-4'>Send Message</h1>
                <br>
                <input id='name' class='form-control' placeholder='Name'>
                <br>
                <textarea id='message' class='form-control' placeholder='Your Message Here'></textarea>
                <br>
                <button id='send' class='btn btn-success'>Send</button>
            </div>
            <div id='messages'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
                    var socket = io();
                    $(() => {
                        $("#send").click(()=>{
                            sendMessage({
                                    name: $("#name").val(),
                                    message:$("#message").val()
                                });
                            });
                            getMessages();
                        }
                    );
                    socket.on('message', addMessages);
                    function addMessages(message){
                        $("#messages").append(`<h4>${message.name}</h4><p>${message.message}</p>`);
                    }
                    function getMessages(){  
                        $.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {data.forEach(addMessages);});
                    }
                    function sendMessage(message){
                        $.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', message); 
                    }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Todo funciona perfectamente, todo se inserta bien en la base de datos, pero no refresca la pagina para ver los mensajes enviados y cuando me fijo en la consola sale el mensaje 
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1559146749555-2
404 Not Found
Cannot GET /socket.io/
y la pagina no se recarga

Comment: No sera que en ves de localhost seria: https://socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1559146749555-2 
tienes la documentacion para ver aqui:
https://socket.io/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta arrancar el servidor usando http en lugar de app

```
// usamos http en lugar de app
const server = http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: cambié <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>  por  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>  y cambié app por http, muchas gracias, funcionó!